# Optimize multiple case expressions with THEN/END

Tags: postgresql

I have following query.

```
SELECT
            i.id,
            CASE WHEN ia.detail_count = 1 THEN i.space_id ELSE NULL END AS space_id,
            CASE WHEN ia.detail_count = 1 THEN i.resident_id ELSE NULL END AS resident_id,
            CASE WHEN ia.detail_count = 1 THEN i.lease_id ELSE NULL END AS lease_id,
            i.deleted_by,
            i.deleted_on,
            i.updated_by,
            i.updated_on,
            i.created_by
From 
            myTable i
JOIN (
                SELECT
                    icd.id,
                    json_build_object(
                        'lease_ids', array_remove(array_agg(icd.lease_id), NULL),
                        'resident_ids', array_remove(array_agg(icd.resident_id), NULL),
                        'space_ids', array_remove(array_agg(icd.space_id), NULL)
                    ) AS details,
                    COUNT(icd.id) As detail_count
                FROM
                    mytable_details icd
                GROUP BY
                    icd.id
            ) ia ON ia.id = i.id;
```

Can we optimize following three expressions into 1, since condition is same only operand is different.

```
CASE WHEN ia.detail_count = 1 THEN i.space_id ELSE NULL END AS space_id,
CASE WHEN ia.detail_count = 1 THEN i.resident_id ELSE NULL END AS resident_id,
CASE WHEN ia.detail_count = 1 THEN i.lease_id ELSE NULL END AS lease_id,
```

Comment: No, you can't. A CASE expression is that: a **single** expression and thus each expression returns a single value. It can not return three different values from three different columns

Comment: You could drop the `ELSE NULL ` from them though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this counts as an optimisation, but I think you could modify the inner query:

```
(COUNT(icd.id) = 1) as one_detail
```

... which would return a Boolean result, and then ...

```
case when one_detail then i.space_id    end as space_id,
case when one_detail then i.resident_id end as resident_id,
case when one_detail then i.lease_id    end as lease_id,
```

I'm not sure it's worthwhile in a simple case like this, but for a more complex condition it might be.